# Facebook Graph API To Fetch Activity Feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am trying to implement same feature **( Your friend's Activity )** in an application

[image]

I am able to fetch the list of my all friends and his profile pictures Through Facebook Grap API by using javascript SDK.

```
FB.api('me/friends?fields=name,picture.width(80).height(80)', function(response){
            ......... 
      })
```

But i just want to fetch the list of those friend who are associated with an **app id** in other words those who have joined my website through facebook. 
 Also is there any way to fetch **activity feed** of a particular user on the basis of **user id** and **app id** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i just want to fetch the list of those friend who are associated with an app id in other words those who have joined my website through facebook.

[Facebook open graph, filtering friends list array](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11810426/facebook-open-graph-filtering-friends-list-array/11810543#11810543)

> Also is there any way to fetch activity feed of a particular user on the basis of user id and app id ?

You can read everything that is public using just your app access token. To get stuff that has limited visibility (for friends only f.e.), you should use the access token of the current user.